# Is it possible to make Apple Magic Mouse behave on Windows exactly as on a Mac?

Tags: macos, windows-7, hardware, magic-mouse

I need to change my mouse and I am looking to buy the Apple magic mouse but I'm not sure if there are drivers to install it on Windows and use it in a way that Magic Mouse functionalities can work fine on Windows. I've read across the internet about a software called "Magic Utilities" in addition to the driver for basic functionality of a standard mouse, however I don't bought the magic mouse yet, then I can't test that. I wanna know if we're completely able to make magic mouse work on Windows 7 (even on Win 8 or 10, I could run an update).

Thanks.

Comment: Questions about general computing activities are off-topic for StackOverflow.  Try **SuperUser**.

Comment: Ok, I've posted the question there. http://superuser.com/questions/1023750/is-it-possible-to-make-apple-magic-mouse-behave-on-windows-exactly-as-on-a-mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work if you have the right drivers but not all Bluetooth dongles work with the Magic Mouse

Comment: Great, thanks for answering. I've ticked yours as accepted.